# zend framework how to use view script decorator with form with dynamically added elements?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, decorator

Zend framework how to use view script decorator with form with dynamically added elements?
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What's a view script decorator? You can alter a form's element decorators via `$form->setElementDecorators()` which will set them for all elements regardless of how they were added.

Comment: I wanted to use someting like this: $this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_form_decorator.phtml')))); and style the form in phtml file with css.

Comment: you can probably use a simple foreach() loop. Show me some code and maybe I can help.

Comment: I have something like in my form class: foreach($options['filterTypes'] as $key => $value){$filterContainer = new App_Form_Element_FilterContainer($value);
                    $filterContainer->setDecorators(array(array('ViewHelper')));
                    $this->addElement($filterContainer);
        }